# How to declare string in C# without having to escape special characters?

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to declare strings in C# without having to escape special characters?

I have searched for answers and found some string literal syntaxes that I thought would achieve what I wanted, but did not.

```
string lit = ""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?""
string lit = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"

error CS1525: Invalid expression term '?'
```

Comment: with `@" ... "` the only thing you need to escape is `"` (escape with `""`)

Comment: Perhaps you want to keep these strings in a resource file instead? That way you don't need to worry about special characters.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to declare strings in C# without having to escape special characters?

When considering `"` as a special character, the answer is no.

Verbatim string literals (`@"foo"`) avoid you having to escape backslashes and line breaks, but you still need to escape double quotes. The correct escaping for your examples would be:

```cs
string lit = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?";
string lit = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?";
```

I often find that for JSON and XML, in test code at least, it's simplest to use single quotes and then replace them:

```cs
string lit = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?".Replace('\'', '"');
```

Or for XML you *could* just use single quotes for attributes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

inside the string literal if we need to use double quote we will still need to escape it in verbatim string too like:

```
string lit = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?";
```

the value in variable will be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
```